# I want to convert this html code using html helper into cakephp But it shows unexpected Behaviour in my layout. How can i fix it?

Tags: cakephp

I want to convert this html code

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Company <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

into `cakephp`  like this:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Company'  $this->Html->tag('b', '', array('class' => 'caret')),
    '#',
    array(
        'class'=>'dropdown-toggle',
        'data-toggle'=>'dropdown',
        'escape'=>false
    )
) ?>
```

But it shows unexpected Behaviour in my layout. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you post the html that it produces?

Comment: Try tou add a string concatenation between 'Company' and the Html->tag : <?php echo $this->Html->link('Company' . $this->Html->tag('b', '', array('class' => 'caret')),'#',array('class'=>'dropdown-toggle','data-toggle'=>'dropdown','escape'=>false))?> <br>

Comment: It is brilliant to tell us that there *is* unexpected behaviour instead of telling us *what* the unexpected behaviour is... So show what is wrong.

Comment: My layout output shows - 'Company <b class="caret"></b>' After implementing  - <?php echo $this->Html->link('Company' . $this->Html->tag('b', '', array('class' => 'caret')),'#',array('class'=>'dropdown-toggle','data-toggle'=>'dropdown','escape‌​'=>false))?>      - This code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link('Company' . $this->Html->tag('b', '', array('class' => 'caret')), '#',
    array('class' => 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown','escape' => false));
?>
```

Comment: Its doesn't helping me. It shows in my display - Company <b class="caret"></b> .But I want my specific sign instead of <b class="caret"></b>.

Answer (score 0):

### Just write plain html

The desired markup in the question contains no variables - unless there's a benefit that isn't mentioned in the question, the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) thing to do is just leave the markup as plain html.

### To use the html helper

If for some reason (I can't really think of any) the markup "must" come from a helper call, at the least it's not necessary to call `tag`:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Company <b class="caret"></b>',
    '#',
    array(
        'class' => 'dropdown-toggle',
        'data-toggle' => 'dropdown',
        'escape' => false
    )
) ?>
```

The use of [escape => false](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link) (which oddly enough is in the code in the question - is the actual code different? the code in the question does exactly what's been asked except for the syntax error) will prevent Cake from converting `<` to `&lt;`.

Comment: After implementing your code in  my page javascript has been lost.Please give another solution.